Diagonalisation of spinless BCS
I am following several references like Kitaev Eqs. (4)-(13) or Bruus Chap 18. "Superconductivity" to study the BCS hamiltonian but I dont understand what negative momentum creation/annahilation operators mean or where they came from exactly. Let me illustrate:
I start with the standard BCS Hamiltonian (see for instance Kitaev):
$$
H_\text{BCS} =  \sum_{j} \mu  c_{j}^\dagger c_{j} + \lambda \left( c_{j}^\dagger c_{j+1} + c_{j+1}^\dagger c_{j}\right) -\Delta \left(e^{-i\phi_c}c^\dagger_{j}c^\dagger_{j+1}+ e^{i\phi_c} c_{j+1}c_{j}\right)
$$
now I change to momentum basis by defining $c_j \doteq \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_k^N e^{ijk \frac{2\pi}{N}} d_k$, that is
$$    
H_\text{BCS} = \sum_k \left( \mu + 2\lambda \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{N} k \right) \right) d^\dagger_k d_k + \left( \Delta e^{-ik\frac{2\pi}{N}} d_k d_{-k} + \Delta^* e^{ik\frac{2\pi}{N}} d_{-k}^\dagger d_{k}^\dagger \right) 
$$
where I wrote $d_{-k}$ just because there was a Kronecker delta that enforced me to, but what does that mean? Before, I was dealing with say $N$ fermions $c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_N$ and now it seems as if I have $2N$, as in $d_{-N},\cdots,d_N$. Wouldnt that imply the operator $d_k$ is larger than $c_j$ too? That seems a dimensionality violation.
I suspect this issue is closely linked with my next issue:
As written above, $H_\text{BCS}$ can be written as
$$
H_\text{BCS} \equiv \sum_k \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 d^\dagger_k & d_{-k} \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \epsilon_k & \Delta^*_k \\
 \Delta_k  &  0 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 d_k \\
 d_{-k}^\dagger \\
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
but in order to get the correct spectrum I think it should be
$$
H_\text{BCS} \equiv \sum_k \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 d^\dagger_k & d_{-k} \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \epsilon_k & \Delta^*_k \\
 \Delta_k  &  -\epsilon_k \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 d_k \\
 d_{-k}^\dagger \\
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
to have as spectrum
$$
\lambda_k = \pm\sqrt{\epsilon_k + |\Delta|^2 }
$$
which I have seen around. In order for me to have that second matrix form, I would need to have negative momentum terms like $\sum_k \left( \mu + 2\lambda \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{N} k \right) \right) d^\dagger_{-k} d_{-k}$ in addition to the $\sum_k \left( \mu + 2\lambda \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{N} k \right) \right) d^\dagger_k d_k$ terms I already found but I dont see where they would come from. As in, in a standard free fermions hopping on a chain, $\sum_{j} \mu  c_{j}^\dagger c_{j} + \lambda \left( c_{j}^\dagger c_{j+1} + c_{j+1}^\dagger c_{j}\right)$, I thought the correct diagonalisation was $\sum_k \left( \mu + 2\lambda \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{N} k \right) \right) d^\dagger_k d_k $.
What am I missing?

PS: here $\epsilon_k = \left( \mu + 2\lambda \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{N} k \right) \right) $ and $\Delta_k = \Delta e^{-ik\frac{2\pi}{N}}$ for brevity.

Which Kronecker forced you? What boundary conditions do you employ? Anyway: Why don't you state page and equation numbers for your cited references? What exactly is Bruus to start with (I can imagine, but I can also imagine many people don't)? ...

@TobiasFünke So I have, $\sum_j c_{j+1}c_j = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{jkp}e^{ip\frac{2\pi}{N}}e^{ij(k+p)\frac{2\pi}{N}} d_k d_p = \frac{1}{N}\ \sum_{kp} e^{ip\frac{2\pi}{N}} d_k d_p \sum_j e^{ij(k+p)\frac{2\pi}{N}} =  \sum_{kp} e^{ip\frac{2\pi}{N}} d_k d_p \delta_{k,-p} = \sum_{k} e^{-ik\frac{2\pi}{N}} d_k d_{-k}$ no? I added more precise refs too.

Ok. Here is one more comment:  a) You should start by explicitly label from where to where you sum $j,k,p$ etc. b) Make sure you use appropriate boundary conditions. c) Assuming the ranges are $j,k,p=1,2,\ldots, N$: For your expression which you transform into the Kronecker delta, note that $k+p=mN$ for $m\in \mathbb Z$ gives a $1$; with the above restrictions, the only integers for which this works is $m=1,2$ because $2\leq k+p\leq 2N$. I don't you what you have in mind/use for a) and b), though, so this is just a wild guess. I also have not checked any of your calculations btw.

Possibly related Math SE thread about the periodic Kronecker delta representation.

@TobiasFünke that's an interesting discussion! That modifies the following $\sum_j c_{j+1}c_j = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{jkp}e^{ip\frac{2\pi}{N}}e^{ij(k+p)\frac{2\pi}{N}} d_k d_p = \frac{1}{N}\ \sum_{kp} e^{ip\frac{2\pi}{N}} d_k d_p \sum_j e^{ij(k+p)\frac{2\pi}{N}}$ as before. Now: $\cdots =  \sum_{kp:k+p\neq mN} e^{ip\frac{2\pi}{N}} d_k d_p \delta_{k,-p} +  \sum_ke^{i(N-k)\frac{2\pi}{N}} d_k d_{N-k} +   \sum_k e^{i(2N-k)\frac{2\pi}{N}} d_k d_{2N-k}$. Now, the last sum should only valid for $k=N$ (otherwise $d_k$ with $k>N$) which then entirely cancels out due to pauli $d_N d_N = 0$.

On the other hand, $\sum_{kp:k+p\neq mN} e^{ip\frac{2\pi}{N}} d_k d_p \delta_{k,-p}=0$ since nor $k$ or $p$ can be negative. We are left with $\sum_k e^{-ik\frac{2\pi}{N}} d_k d_{N-k}$ and by hermitian conjugate $\sum_j d_j^\dagger d^\dagger_{j+1}=- \sum_k e^{ik\frac{2\pi}{N}} d_k^\dagger d_{N-k}^\dagger$ which explains the $-k$ business.

Actually this solves everything!

Great. Consider to write an answer yourself, it might help potential future readers with similar problem(s).
